# Change IntelliJ Breadcrumbs Style

Tags: intellij-idea, styling, breadcrumbs

Somehow I have messed up the breadcrumbs color and i can't figure out, how to change the color for the breadcrumbs. Every reference i can find is about how to navigate with them.

I believe they used to be brighter, but I can't figure out, how to change it. Even going back to default Theme and again moving to Darcula didn't change it.

[image: messed up colors]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's under `Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > HTML`. Change the background colors for `Tag tree (level x)` to change the color both in the editor and the breadcrumbs. Level 1 is your current element, level 2 is the parent element. So in your example, `html` is level 6.

[image]

However, the colors do not look exactly as the colors you define. Use this example:

```
<div class="c6">
    <div class="c5">
        <div class="c4">
            <div class="c3">
                <div class="c2">
                    <div class="c1"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and place your cursor within `c1`. It should look something like this:

[image]

My color for `c1` is `#FF0000`, but it looks like violet in the editor and brown in the breadcrumbs. When you change the color and click `Apply`, both places will change the color though.

Comment: it does not affect the breadcrubs. the colos are set to somewhat bright colors, like ping(FF00FF). None of the breadcrumbs is anywhere near that color.

Comment: I've updated my answer. It's true - the colors you define are not the same as in the breadcrumbs and the editor, but they *do* change the color in those places. You need to experiment a little to get exactly the colors you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try Preferences > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General. (I guess it's Settings > Editor > Colors & Fonts > General on Windows.)

Then in the right-hand side outline, Editor > Breadcrumbs.

[image: breadcrumbs settings]